# Prove a functional (f-divergence + entropy) is $\lambda$-geodesically convex

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I was wondering if it is possible to prove a certain functional is $\lambda$-geodesically convex, and how might one go about doing so.

The functional in question is defined in the 2-Wasserstein space ($\mathcal{P}_2(\Omega), \mathcal{W_2}$), the space of probability measures with finite second moments and the 2-Wasserstein metric.

Define $\mathcal{F} : \mathcal{P}_2(\Omega) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}(\rho) = \int f(\rho(x)/\mu(x))\mu(x)dx + \gamma \int \rho(x) \log \rho(x) dx
\end{equation}
where $f$ is twice-differentiable convex function with $f(1)=0$, i.e., the [f-divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-divergence). The second term is the negative entropy. $\rho(x)$ and $\mu(x)$ are probability measures. I would like to prove if $\mathcal{F}$ is $\lambda$-geodesically convex.

Definiton of $\lambda$-geodesically convex: Let $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ be the distance. A functional $\mathcal{F}$ is $\lambda$-geodesically convex if for any $v_0, v_1 \in Domain(\mathcal{F})$, there exists a geodesic $\gamma$ with $\gamma_0 = v_0, \gamma_1 = v_1, d(\gamma_s, \gamma_t) = d(\gamma_0, \gamma_1)(t-s), \forall 0 \leq t \leq s \leq 1$ such that
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}(\gamma_t) \leq (1-t)\mathcal{F}(\gamma_0) + t \mathcal{F}(\gamma_1) - \frac{1}{2}\lambda t(1-t)d^2(\gamma_0, \gamma_1).
\end{equation}

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you looked into the book by Ambrosio, Gigli and Savaré (2005) on this topic?

Comment: @Ramanujan I have looked into it but couldn't find which parts would be helpful. Do you have any suggestions as to which chapter/page it could be at? I'm not the strongest at reading very math-heavy books.